# Xamarin/Android - Make a modal window that waits like MessageBox.Show from C# .NET

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been working on porting an application to Android from .NET WinForms for a client, and I have run into a snag with a requirement for Dialogs that wait for user interaction before continuing.

I'll say this now, up front. While I'm relatively new to Android, I am aware that this is frowned upon in Android because of impacts on the UI thread. I understand this, however, I've been told in no uncertain terms they want it the same way it works on .NET and I fail to see how async methods and callbacks will allow me to do that without massively re-organizing their routines (against, their wishes). So, for the purpose of this question, doing it the generally ideal way is not an option for me.

I have tried some different options to achieve the result I want, nothing has been 100%. I am close though with this:

```
public class MessageBox
{
    public class mHandler : Handler
    {
        public override void HandleMessage(Message mesg)
        {
            throw new MessageBoxException();
        }
    }

    public class MessageBoxException : Exception
    {
        public MessageBoxException()
        {
        }

        public MessageBoxException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public MessageBoxException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }
    }

    public enum MessageBoxResult
    {
        Positive, Negative, Ignore, Cancel, Closed
    };

    private static Handler handler;
    private static MessageBoxResult yesNoDialogResult;

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Context context, String title, String message, String positiveMessage, String negativeMessage)
    {
        yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Closed;
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.SetTitle(title);
        alert.SetMessage(message);
        alert.SetCancelable(false);
        alert.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);

        handler = new mHandler();
        alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Positive;
            handler.SendMessage(handler.ObtainMessage());
        });

        alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Negative;
            handler.SendMessage(handler.ObtainMessage());
        });

        alert.Show(); 

        try { Looper.Loop(); }
        catch (MessageBoxException exc) { }

        return yesNoDialogResult;
    }
}
```

I have created a MessageBox class with a Show(). To make it wait, I am using a custom Handler and the main Looper to trigger a custom Exception, which I am then handling.

At runtime, this all works, quite well actually. The problem I'm having however is that when I debug my application using Visual Studio 2013, it always breaks when I throw my exception.

To combat this, I've tried changing my Exception settings to never break on my custom exception, to no avail. I've also tried the use of [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden] to bypass debugging the error, but all that accomplished was moving the point where it fails from inside the Show or Handler to instead the .Show() method call when I tried to use it.

If anyone can point me in the right direction here for either a fix to this, or another workable solution, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `EventWaitHandle` to make a AlertDialog "modal":

```
public class MessageBox
{
    public enum MessageBoxResult
    {
        Positive, Negative, Ignore, Cancel, Closed
    };

    private static MessageBoxResult yesNoDialogResult;

    public static async Task<MessageBoxResult> Show(Context context, String title, String message, String positiveMessage, String negativeMessage)
    {
        yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Closed;
        var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
           .SetTitle(title).SetMessage(message)
           .SetCancelable(false)
           .SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);

        var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Positive;
            waitHandle.Set();
        });

        alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            yesNoDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Negative;
            waitHandle.Set();
        });

        alert.Show();
        await Task.Run(() => waitHandle.WaitOne());
        return yesNoDialogResult;
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
button.Click += async delegate { 
    Console.WriteLine("MessageBox.Show");
    var answer = await MessageBox.Show(this, "Stack", "Overflow", "", "");
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
};
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! What if I wanted to call it from somewhere other than a button click? It tells me the calling method needs to be marked as async. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Sypher_04 You need the async due to the `Show` method that contains the `await Task.Run(() => waitHandle.WaitOne());` line. This `await Task.Run` is required in order to NOT block the UI thread, otherwise you would deadlock yourself and the `AlertDialog` would hang and the Android OS would eventually report that the app is not responding and do you want to kill it.

Comment: @Sypher_04 FYI: You could spin up your own thread and skip the async/await setup, the *main thing* is not to block the UI while waiting (somewhere) for the `EventWaitHandle` to be set.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I think I can get all the necessary calls into button clicks, so this shouldn't be a huge problem. Somewhat related question... when I was testing this out last night, I found that if I clicked the button while it was processing, when it completed I'd get another messagebox come up. I tried to disable this by setting SetClickable = false, and SetEnabled = false at the beginning of my Button click handler, and then both true at the end. This didn't work though; fired anyway as soon as the button click handler completed.

Comment: @Sypher_04 I'm not sure I understand the "I can get all the necessary calls into button clicks", any method can be flagged as `async` so you can `await` something in that method, does not have to be an event delegate. As far as your question, I'm lost in your description of the problem, best to post another question to show the code and the issue you are having.

Comment: True, but if I call an async method from somewhere that isn't already async I would get an error would I not? I have several methods for my button to hand off to, I suppose I just meant that I have a button event handler at the beginning of it all.