# How to ask permission on splash screen and quit if denied?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make my Xamarin.Android app ask for permission on the splash screen which is the first activity to be launched.

I'm using the [permission plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin).
I'm also using an [async modal dialog implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968263/15186).

Here is the permission related code for the splash screen activity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

private async Task<bool> RequestPermissionsAndTellIfWeShouldContinueAsync()
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
        {
            await Utilities.MessageBox.Show(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.explain_external_storage_permission_title), Resources.GetString(Resource.String.explain_external_storage_permission_text), true);
        }
        var newStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new Permission[] { Permission.Storage });

        var result = newStatus.Values.ElementAt(0);
        if (result == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (result == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            await Utilities.MessageBox.Show(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.cant_continue_without_permission_title), Resources.GetString(Resource.String.cant_continue_without_permission_text), true);
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

}

Next is the code that tries to ask for permission on the OnResume callback

```
    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        bool shallWeContinue = await RequestPermissionsAndTellIfWeShouldContinueAsync();

        if ( shallWeContinue)
        {
          // Start Main activity

        }
        else
        {
            // End current activity and go back to android launcher
            Finish();
        }


    }
```

This is working fine as long as I accept the permission request.
If I deny it twice, my problem is that I'm entering an infinite loop displaying the last Messagebox that explains that the permission should now be granted by hand in the application options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `onResume` is called each time after the permission dialog disappears - it's a standard Android behavior. Move the `onResume` logic to `onStart` or `onCreate` method to avoid the loop.

Comment: Moving the logic to onCreate solved the problem. Thank you so much that was driving me crazy.